# Update source in datagrid via selection from combo box

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, mvvm, combobox

I am new to WPF and the MVVM design pattern. Consequently, everything I try to do seems to take a long time.

Currently, I am using a Combobox to select a list. I want to populate a Gridview with all the contacts that are in that list and to refresh that Gridview every time the Combobox selection changes.

The XAML for the view follows. How can I get the Gridview to listen for a change in the Combobox selection? I need the Combobox selection to set it's property so that I can query the db to return those records associated with the list so my first thought was to add a button to fire the command but it never fires. I have read on google where it says the Gridview should listen for the PropertyUpdated but no sample on just how to do that.

I tried this in the Gridview but throws an exception and yes my ViewModel does implement INotifyProperyChanged

PropertyChanged="{Binding Path=SelectedListNameContactView}

Your help is appreciated.

```
<UserControl x:Name="manageLists"
         x:Class="Five9ContactManagement.ManageListsView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Five9ContactManagement.Controls;assembly=Five9ContactManagement.Controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="400"
         d:DesignWidth="400"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Five9ContactManagement">


 <Grid>
   <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center"
         VerticalAlignment="Top"
         Margin="20">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition />
       <ColumnDefinition />
       <ColumnDefinition />
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <TextBlock  Grid.Column="0"
              Grid.Row="2"
              Text="Select List "
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Margin="5" />

      <ComboBox Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.Row="2"
            ItemsSource="{Binding GetLists, Mode=OneWay}"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            SelectedIndex="-1"
            SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedListNameContactView />

            <Button Grid.Row="2"
                 Grid.Column="2"
                 Content="View Contacts"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 Margin="5" 
                 Width=" 100"
                Command="{Binding Path=ShowContactsCommand}"   
                CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedListNameContactView}"/>

</Grid>
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center"
      VerticalAlignment="Center"
      Margin="20"
      RenderTransformOrigin="1.25,2.662">

  <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="contactsGrid"
                       GroupRenderMode="Flat"
                       ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}"
                       PropertyChanged="{Binding Path=SelectedListNameContactView}                                
                             AutoGenerateColumns="False"

                             CanUserFreezeColumns="False"
                             RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed"
                             CanUserResizeColumns="True"
                             Margin="5,5,5,5" 
                             IsReadOnly="True">
      <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
      <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="First Name"
                                  DataMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}"
                                  Width="100" />
      <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Last Name"
                                  DataMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}"
                                  Width="100" />
      <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Address"
                                  DataMemberBinding="{Binding Address}"
                                  Width="200" />
      <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Address2"
                                  DataMemberBinding="{Binding Address2}"
                                  Width="75" />
      <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="City"
                                  DataMemberBinding="{Binding City}"
                                  Width="75" />
      <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="State"
                                  DataMemberBinding="{Binding State}" />
      <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Zip"
                                  DataMemberBinding="{Binding ZipCode}"
                                  Width="75" />
      <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Phone"
                                  DataMemberBinding="{Binding PhoneNumber}"
                                  Width="75" />
      <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Media Group"
                                  DataMemberBinding="{Binding MediaGroup}"
                                  Width="100" />
      <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Brochure Date"
                                  DataMemberBinding="{Binding BrochureDate}"
                                  Width="100" />
    </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
  </telerik:RadGridView>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using MVVM, for functionality like this, we work with the view model rather than the views. First add a property of the same type as the items in the `ComboBox` control... I'm going to assume that they are `string` values for simplicity's sake:

```
private string selectedItem = string.Empty;
...
public string SelectedItem
{
    get { return selectedItem; }
    set
    {
        selectedItem = value;
        NotifyPropertyChange("SelectedItem"); // << Implement INotifyPropertyChanged
        UpdateGrid();
    }
}
```

Now add a collection property for your `DataGrid`:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
...
public ObservableCollection<string> Items
{
    get { return items; }
    set
    {
        items= value;
        NotifyPropertyChange("Items"); // << Implement INotifyPropertyChanged
    }
}
```

Now let's look at that `UpdateGrid` method:

```
private void UpdateGrid()
{
    // Update your property that is bound to the DataGrid.ItemsSource here
    Items = GetNewData(); // << You need to implement this method yourself
}
```

Now, in XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollectionNotShownHere}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
```

Now whenever the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` changes, the `SelectedItem` property setter will be called and that will call the `UpdateGrid()` method, which will update the `Items` collection property and that will update the collection in the `DataGrid`. As the comment in the example said, you *will* need to implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface in your view model.

Comment: That is exactly how I have it set up. The grid does not populate and it is returning records.  If I set the initial grid to display records associated with one of my lists it populates fine. Select something from combo box it hits the code but grid does not update. In winforms you could do a refresh. Not with WPF. I found a link which basically reloads the app which in essence redraws it. Unless I find a better answer here I am going to give it a shot. here is the link btw.   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/158591/Resetting-a-View-Model-in-WPF-MVVM-applications-wi

Comment: Good grief...I forgot to raise the OnPropertyChanged event for my collection....thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

if you will use Interactivity and interactions librarys, you will be able to write in xaml something like :

```
 <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedComboBoxItem, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxItems}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnCopmboBoxSelectionChangedCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </ComboBox>
```

and command in viewModel :

```
 private ICommand _onCopmboBoxSelectionChangedCommand;
 public ICommand OnCopmboBoxSelectionChangedCommand
 {
     get
     {
         if (_onCopmboBoxSelectionChangedCommand != null) return _onCopmboBoxSelectionChangedCommand;
         _onCopmboBoxSelectionChangedCommand = new RelayCommand(OnCopmboBoxSelectionChanged);
         return _onCopmboBoxSelectionChangedCommand;
     }
 }
```

Finally  method in viewModel :

```
 private void OnCopmboBoxSelectionChanged(object sender)
 { }
```